# Does \ return the coefficient of linear regression in Julia?

Tags: julia, regression

I was following the GitHub Copilot codes on writing a function that gets a Matrix and fits a single variable linear regression on each row of the Matrix against time, and I was confronted with a strange procedure:

```
function fᵢ(adj_price::Matrix{Float64})
  n_assets, n_days = size(adj_price)
  n_days > 1 || ArgumentError("") |> throw
  t = 1:n_days
  # Fit a linear regression on each row of the adjusted price \
  # matrix against t and store the gradients in aᵢ Vector.
  aᵢ = zeros(n_assets)
  for i in 1:n_assets
    aᵢ[i] = adj_price[i, :] \ t
  end
  return aᵢ
end
```

The point is to store the gradient of each regression model in a Vector and return the Vector as the final output. So, a regression should be fitted on each row of the Matrix against a variable of time, to achieve its coefficient (gradient). My question lies where we have `adj_price[i, :] \ t`. Does this small operation achieve the coefficient?

Comment: Yes, see: `https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.:\\-Tuple{AbstractMatrix,%20AbstractVecOrMat}`

Comment: @GKi, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, it's useful to look at the docs:

```
help?> \
search: \

  \(x, y)


  Left division operator: multiplication of y by the inverse of x on the left.
```

So in your basic linear regression:

y = X * b

where y is your outcome, X is your matrix of regressors and b is the covariate vector, multiplying both sides of the equation by the inverse of X gets you

X \ y = b

which is what linear regression computes.

Note that this is different from the simple regression

```
lm(@formula(y ~ X), data)
```

that one might run using GLM, as the `@formula` macro by default includes an intercept term, so you are fitting

y = a + Xb

instead. To replicate this with `\` you'd have to do

```
[ones(length(y)) X] \ y
```

to manually include the intercept column in your regressor matrix.

Comment: To be precise, by the left-inverse, as X is not normally square..